# Xcode will run app on simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4

I receive the following error when trying to run the app on my device.

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Word Processor.app/Word Processor' -- No such file or directory (/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Word Processor.app/Word Processor)
```

The app runs fine in the simulator. When I try to debug on the device, it appears to copy the app (I can see the icon), but then stalls with the above message. Xcode says it is running the app on my iPod, but nothing is happening on my iPod.

When I click on the app, the app appears to launch, but seems to be missing resources.
Other projects of mine work properly. What setting do I need to change to make this work properly.? Looking at the error message, it seems to be looking in my mac for the app. But this doesn't make sense since I am trying to run it on my 4th gen iPod touch. I am using Xcode 4.3.1 and iOS 5.1

Comment: Weird. It seems to have sorted itself out by restarting Xcode. It is still missing resources though. But after one run, the error returns again.

Comment: Seems intermittent. The problem is gone again.

Comment: I am having a similar problem where it runs fine on the simulators, but seems to be copying all of the files over when I try to run on device.

Comment: I'm seeing this for the first time today.  I have two branches of a project that both run fine, but I can't debug from trunk...  Weird.  Also, if I copy trunk and put it elsewhere (desktop) it runs fine.  Seems there are some hidden files that are mucking things up.  :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The app works fine in the simulator using the iphone or ipad scheme, but if i attach my itouch, it gets that same error message (failed to launch ... failed to get task for process). However, it installs itself on the Touch, and i can run the app just fine on the Touch, just not on the Touch through the simulator. Happens every time. The same app works fine on my iPhone, so it's specific to the simulator with a device attached. Another app i developed does not have this issue. I tried deleting the DerivedData for this app, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

With Mountain Lion and the latest version of Xcode (4.4.4F250), none of the suggestions in this thread worked directly (clean, clean project, remove derived data folder, etc). This sequence did. From [DhilipSiva](http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html):

1. Disconnect your device
2. Delete the app from your device
3. Quit Xcode (Don't just simply close the window, quit it)
4. Delete derived data folder `rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` (console)
5. Start Xcode,connect device & run the project

Comment: This worked for me as well with Lion, Xcode 4.4, iPad 3 - just deleting the DerivedData folder did not work nor cleaning project, etc.  I also did a device targeted build before then connecting my iPad and running debug.  At least I'm running again... this new flood of bugs from Apple is really frustrating.

Comment: P.S.  Unfortunately I have to repeat this process frequently - definitely any time something changes the profile being used.

Comment: Worked for me - after trying many other things which didn't. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but does anyone have any ideas as to why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 15):

I solve this by going to Targets-> Info -> Required Device capabilities and delete the option with armv7.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed, make sure that the device you want to run it on satisfies the Required Device Capabilities! If that's your problem, deleting the DerivedData folder isn't the solution.

Comment: Oh man. Thx Chronos! I don´t know why there´s just an other error message than "could not launch no such file or directory".

Comment: I dont see any "require device captabilities" in the latest xcode version, is the same that supported architectures?

Answer (score 14):

This is a recurring problem that many developers are having with the current version of Xcode. The temporary workaround has been consistently deleting the DerivedData folder.

You can add doing it to a build script or even make it a cron job:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Sad, but true.

Comment: Is everything in the DerivedData folder auto-regenerated upon relaunch?  Otherwise, do we have to worry about configurations?  I use git and store my main project file....so I'm guessing I'll be ok...

Comment: I have deleted the DerivedData folder, and haven't had any bad side-effects so far.  Is it also safe to delete the following folders under a given _.xcodeproj/ folder? "xcuserdata" and "project.xcworkspace" (I currently just ignore them in my .gitignore file.)

Comment: @mda I'm not sure. Another dev suggested to me that running the Clean Build Folder command in Xcode (hold down the option key and choose it from the Product menu) does the same thing, deleting Derived Data, but I've not tested it. If so then you can see if it also clears out xcuserdata. project.xcworkspace is where things like currently-open Xcode tabs and currently-visible panels are stored, so deleting it -- if it doesn't damage the project -- should only mean you'll lose that information. Not sure what all is in xcuserdata.

Comment: it doesn't fix the problem for me

Answer (score 9):

For me restarting of Xcode, cleaning DerivedData and restaring device wasn't enough in most cases, until I had figured out that iTunes was also running, and after quitting iTunes everything worked fine!

So my steps now are simple:

**1. Quit Xcode.**
**2. If iTunes is running, quit iTunes.**
**3. Reopen project.**

No need to remove app from the device, clean project or restart/disconnect device.
I think that's because Xcode and iTunes use some common libraries (as you know, Xcode Installer always asks to quit iTunes on installing iOS SDK).

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem after changing from a lower XCode and iOS version to the current XCode and iOS version.

I fixed this problem by changing th iOS Depolyment Target to a lower version, since my Device is not updated to the latest iOS yet.
You can do this by clicking the project inside the Info tab.

Comment: Recently I faced such kind of problem & I tried each solution given in the all answers here, but this helped me. Thanks ! And with this answer I'm helping you to get a silver badge by upvoting this

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the Developer Certs and Distribution Certs if you have. When running in debug mode from Xcode your will need your app assigned with the developer cert and not the distribution cert. The distribution certs do not allow for debugging.

Comment: This was my issue. I mistakenly selected my distribution certificate to be used as the code signing identity for the Debug build configuration. My project built and ran on the device, but I couldn't see any console logging and Xcode errored with "Could not launch task, failed to get task for process."

Switching back to the developer certificate fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This error will manifest whenever the device capabilities described in the Info.plist do not match those of the device.

In my case, I was requesting GPS support and location-services support and trying to test on an iPod touch.

Comment: thank you, i had set capability as sms which the ipad did not have and thus was not finding the file/folder, strange

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this problem for 2 days and went through all the posts, tried all the options including, restarting Xcode, device, deleting DerivedData folder etc.

Finally, the problem was with the Info.plist file. In my case, I had improper icon paths in the Info.plist file. I suggest you to archive the application and then validate it to get the exact problem in you case. Only when I did that, I was able to find the issue.

Comment: This answer provided the clue for me which solved my problem but only on one of 2 iPad devices. In my case font files which were specified in ino.plist were missing from my project file. However on the other iPad 1 device no solutions presented  so far work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem many times with [DhilipSiva](http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html)'s solution. However, it may not work sometimes. If that is the case, consider deleting and re-adding the target.

Answer (score 2):

Removed armv6 support and it started working again

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this same problem on several diferent projects, researched a lot on forums and even here on Stack overflow. A lot of solutions were given, and some people seemed to get them working, but none of them worked for me.
So we tried some pretty obvious course of action, which for some reason we didn't tought about before: I've done a CHMOD -R 777 on the EXACT path indicated by the error message (I copied it directly).

Worked like a charm, 100% times!

Hope it helps, guys!

Answer (score 1):

As Chronos mentiod, the device capabilities might be the reason. In addition I would say that in my case it was all about the **UIRequiresPersistentWiFi** key, which (for some unclear reason) didn't let me to install my app on an iPhone4. Hope this helps ones who tried everything else and haven't fixed the problem yet.

Comment: UPD: On iOS 8 GM with XCode 6 GM this problem appears for no reason at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by going to Targets-> Info -> Required Device capabilities and check id at 0 index if armv7 not in 0 index then remove other things and armv7 set on 0 index and clean app connect device and run.

Hope this helps fine!

Answer (score 0):

I did these steps:

1. Delete derived data: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
2. Deep cleaned the project: Shift Key + Option Key + Command Key + letter K key
3. Quit the project
4. Quit XCode
5. Deleted the app from my device

When I reopened the Xcode, launched the project, and then launched the app it successively ran on my device

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `Command Line Tools`
Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools

Make sure you select latest Xcode version. I selected Xcode 11.0, and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

I get the similar question and has searched via the internet the whole day without solution yet...

`Xcode 12, iOS 14.`

I'm using a cocoaPods call `GCDWebServer`, which will open a build-in http service in iOS. Now it works fine in simulator and I could open a home page of it in my Mac's browser. But I cannot open the home page if running it with real iPhone. The browser said "Cannot connect to server"

And in console, everything is same without any errors provided for me.
Thus, how could I debug this?

```
[DEBUG] Did open IPv4 listening socket 3
[DEBUG] Did open IPv6 listening socket 4
[INFO] GCDWebUploader started on port 80 and reachable at http://192.168.1.3/
```