# Resizes on simulator but not on the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, resize, autolayout

I have got a rather strange issue, when I try my app I made on the xCode simulator it resizes perfectly. However when I run it on an iPad its size does not increase to fit the iPads screen!

I have used auto layout and got Xcode to add all the missing constraints, I haven't added in any other constraints.

Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Right, so I figured out why it was not filling the entire screen. This is all thanks to DhilipSiva and the answer is seen here -> [Xcode will run app on simulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987192/xcode-will-run-app-on-simulator-but-not-on-device?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the mention :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of layout means your app development according to iPhone not for ipad

Ipad -1024 * 768

IPhone  - is dependent on version like

IPhone 4 - 320 * 480

Comment: K so check size is change when you select ipad in xib if it's not change according to ipad it's means problem in layout otherwise simulator problem then restart your xcode

Comment: Click on xib and select viewcontroller after check activitie inspector and change infrared to desire size which u want

Comment: I don't understand why I'd do that, shouldn't autloayout resize it for me any way?

Comment: Click on view controller in xib and on right side check simulator metric. And change size