# Error on iPhone but not on the simulator

Tags: swift, ios-simulator

Since today i was running my app on Simulator with the 6s on iOS 10, but now I am running it on the iPhone 7. It shows me the following error when i press the `Save` button: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x000cfba4)`

My code look like this:

```
@IBAction func SaveAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let dataString = DateTextfield.text
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"

    // convert string into date
    let dateValue:NSDate? = dateFormatter.date(from: dataString!) as NSDate?

    let nowDouble = dateValue?.timeIntervalSince1970
    let hey = Int64(nowDouble!*1000)   //Here is the error 
    let newdouble = Double(hey)


    MyArray[Work]!["Date"]?.append(newdouble)

}
```

In the iOS simulator it works fine it saves the `newdouble` correctly to the dictionary named `MyArray`

If i run the app with Build Configuration: Debug

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
    0x100385174 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!
    0x100385178 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
    0x10038517c <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]
    0x100385180 <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #48]
    0x100385184 <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #64]
    0x100385188 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #64              ; =64 
    0x10038518c <+24>:  mov    x19, x6
    0x100385190 <+28>:  mov    x20, x5
    0x100385194 <+32>:  mov    x21, x4
    0x100385198 <+36>:  mov    x22, x3
    0x10038519c <+40>:  mov    x23, x2
    0x1003851a0 <+44>:  mov    x24, x1
    0x1003851a4 <+48>:  mov    x25, x0
    0x1003851a8 <+52>:  adr    x8, #936952               ; protocol descriptor for Swift.CVarArg + 88
    0x1003851ac <+56>:  nop    
    0x1003851b0 <+60>:  add    x0, x8, #16               ; =16 
    0x1003851b4 <+64>:  movz   w1, #0x28
    0x1003851b8 <+68>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x1003851bc <+72>:  bl     0x1003854a0               ; rt_swift_allocObject
    0x1003851c0 <+76>:  mov    x8, x0
    0x1003851c4 <+80>:  stp    x22, x21, [x8, #16]
    0x1003851c8 <+84>:  strb   w20, [x8, #32]
    0x1003851cc <+88>:  str    w19, [x8, #36]
    0x1003851d0 <+92>:  adr    x3, #241008               ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
    0x1003851d4 <+96>:  nop    
    0x1003851d8 <+100>: mov    x0, x25
    0x1003851dc <+104>: mov    x1, x24
    0x1003851e0 <+108>: mov    x2, x23
    0x1003851e4 <+112>: mov    x4, x8
    0x1003851e8 <+116>: bl     0x100278b70               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x1003851ec <+120>: brk    #0x1 //Error message here
```

Comment: post more information about the error

Comment: Go to breakpoints tab in Xcode and add a new Exception breakpoint - It will show you which line is crashing

Comment: what is the `DateTextfield.text` value?

Comment: @Alistra I have already done that in the code above i have add a comment in the line that is crashing

Comment: @Mina The current value of DateTextfield.text is "Dec 18, 2016"

Comment: i have build and run your code and there is no error in device and simulator.

Comment: @Mina okay.. what does that mean? Do I have to start the App again? (What device are you using?)

Comment: i have built on iPhone 6s+
but i have commented this code:  `MyArray[Work]!["Date"]?.append(newdouble)` , are you sure there is no problem with this?
clean your project and build again

Comment: @Mina Yes because I test it with an other variable

Comment: read this thread, it maybe helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11770434/1724845

Comment: @Mina thanks but it does not change the problem.. did you use this line: `let hey = Int64(nowDouble!*1000)` in your code?

Comment: yes i do, 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e0liyhmrr7vsoh/Screen%20Shot%201395-09-28%20at%2015.42.32.png?dl=0

Comment: @Mina Finally i found what was wrong, the dateFormater should be like this: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"` Because thats how the textField.text value is. I was wrong when i said you it was this:  "Dec 18, 2016", that's how it truly is: "18 Dec 2016". But I still don't understand why it worked on the simulator! Thanks for your time!! <3

Comment: glad to hear that
good luck

Comment: I suspect setting the value of `DateTextfield.text` (code missing)  somehow depends on the on the region that the device is setup for. Your simulators region is set to "US" but the device is set to the region you are in (non US) for instance. Thus this value differs.