# IONIC app is not running in iPhone device Xcode 10

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, code-signing

I had successfully ran the ionic application via my free apple id with xcode 9, but after upgrading xcode to version 10, when I try to run the app it says:

[image]

I have done automatically managed signing with my free apple id and everything is set up perfectly. Is it something related to xcode 10? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987192/xcode-will-run-app-on-simulator-but-not-on-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode go to file => Workspace settings => Build System, select **Legacy Build System**, this fixed the problem for me if the problem persists go to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) login and click on certificates then go to Provisioning profile verify that provisioning profile status is active, if it is not active make it active, download it, double-click on it and run your code again.

Comment: It did the trick, thank you so much. But can you please explain what exactly is the **Legacy Build System**.

Comment: @iPeter At this point, I don't know much about build system, what I do know is they have an updated build system in Xcode 10 and it is very strict compared to the legacy build system this I got from Apple's website - **Xcode 10 uses a new build system. The new build system provides improved reliability and builds performance, and it catches project configuration problems that the legacy build system does not**. I guess it's just the workaround that we are doing, it's not the proper solution. take a look here: https://apple.co/2CDKCoC